# NextJS webpack: Asset Modules Plugin has been initialized using a generator object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm using NextJS and in `next.config`, I'm using some custom webpack configs.

My `next.config.js` file is as follows:

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  distDir: 'dist',
  i18n,
  images: {
    domains: ['aws-link', 'my-site'],
  },
}

module.exports = {
  webpack: function(config, {isServer}) {
    if (config.mode === 'production' && config.name === 'client') {
      if (!isServer && process.env.ANALYZE === 'true') {
        const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
        config.plugins.push(
          new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            reportFilename: './analyze/client.html',
            generateStatsFile: true
          })
        );
      }

      // 'filename' is specific to 'asset/resource' type only, but incompatible with 'asset/inline',
      // see https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#custom-output-filename.
      // Here we rename generator['asset'] into generator['asset/resource'] to avoid conflicts with inline assets.
      // if (config.module.generator?.asset?.filename) {
      //   if (!config.module.generator['asset/resource']) {
      //     config.module.generator['asset/resource'] = config.module.generator.asset
      //   }
      //   delete config.module.generator.asset
      // }

      config.plugins.push(
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
      )

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        parser: { dataUrlCondition: { maxSize: 50000 } },
      })

      config.module.rules.push({ test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2)$/i, type: "asset/resource", generator: {
        outputPath: 'public/',
        publicPath: 'public/'
      } });

      config.module.rules.push({ test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/i, type: "asset/resource", generator: {
        outputPath: 'public/', // this is the new option set
        publicPath: 'public/'
      }});

  //     config.module.rules.push({
  //       test: /\.(png|jpg|webp|gif|svg|mp4|webm|ico|mp3)$/,
  //       type: 'asset',
  //       parser: { dataUrlCondition: { maxSize: 150000 } },
  // })

      config.optimization = {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'async',
          minSize: 20000,
          minChunks: 1,
          maxAsyncRequests: 30,
          maxInitialRequests: 30,
          enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
          cacheGroups: {
            defaultVendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              priority: -10,
              reuseExistingChunk: true
            },
            default: {
              minChunks: 2,
              priority: -20,
              reuseExistingChunk: true
            }
          }
        }
      };

    } 

    return config;
  },
  ...nextConfig
}

// module.exports = {
  
//   ...nextConfig,
// }
```

But, I'm getting an error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css
Module not found: Invalid generator object. Asset Modules Plugin has been initialized using a generator object that does not match the API schema.
 - generator has an unknown property 'filename'. These properties are valid:
   object { dataUrl? }
   -> Generator options for asset/inline modules.
```

I tried to follow this solution from a github answer:

```
if (config.module.generator?.asset?.filename) {
        if (!config.module.generator['asset/resource']) {
          config.module.generator['asset/resource'] = config.module.generator.asset
        }
        delete config.module.generator.asset
      }
```

But, this just messed all my imports and no css is loaded. I'd really appreciate some help here as I've wasted the whole day searching for solutions.

By the way, this is my folder structure:

pages/

public/

```
 --fonts/

 --gif/

 --png/

 --svg/
```

And, this is how I'm using those images in my components:

`import arrow from '../../public/svg/select-arrow.svg'`

All of this was working fine until I decided to add this in my `next.config.js`:

```
config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        parser: { dataUrlCondition: { maxSize: 50000 } },
      })
```

P.S: I've nearly tried all of the solutions on here but they don't solve my problem so please don't mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates an issue with the `generator` object in your webpack configuration: it contains an unknown property `filename`. According to the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#general-asset-type), the `generator` for asset modules only recognizes the `dataUrl` property.

To resolve this error, update your `generator` configuration for the `asset/resource` type to remove the `filename` property. Also, ensure the `parser` is outside the `rules`.

Here’s the corrected configuration:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2)$/i, 
  type: "asset/resource", 
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'public/',
    publicPath: 'public/'
  } 
});

config.module.rules.push({ 
  test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/i, 
  type: "asset/resource", 
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'public/', // this is the new option set
    publicPath: 'public/'
  }
});
```

For the CSS rule, ensure the parser is not inside the rule configuration:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
});
```

If you want to apply a dataUrlCondition for assets, you can do it like this:

```js
config.module.rules.push({ 
  test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/i, 
  type: "asset/resource", 
  parser: { dataUrlCondition: { maxSize: 50000 } },
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'public/', // this is the new option set
    publicPath: 'public/'
  }
});
```

After making these changes, try running your Next.js application again to see if the error is resolved.